# Javascript Regex to look for characters and wrap text with span dynamically

Tags: javascript, regex

So I'm trying to replace this:

```
<h1>My Title &lt;INTRO&gt;</h1>
```

With this:

```
<h1>My Title <span>&lt;INTRO&gt;</span></h1>
```

But...

In a way that dynamically looks for all instances of text wrapped in `&lt; ... &gt;` and wraps that in span tags.

Something like the code below, but I can't get the regex right.

```
str = str.replace(/(?<=&lt;)\r\n(?=&gt;)/, "<span>$1</span>");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
(&lt;[\s\S]*?&gt;)
```

And replace with:

```
<span>$1</span>
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rL7dX9/3)

**Js Code:**

```js
var str = "<h1>My Title &lt;INTRO&gt;</h1>"
str = str.replace(/(&lt;[\s\S]*?&gt;)/, "<span>$1</span>");
alert(str);
```

Comment: What do the parentheses in the regexp do?

Comment: @torazaburo they will put the match in a `captured group`.. i.e whatever is matched between the 1st group of parentheses will be remembered as `$1` (capture group 1)

Comment: If I run that code snippet, is that running Js on my machine?

Comment: @sln yes.. it runs on your browser if you have javascript plugin enabled.. (which is true by default for most browsers)

Comment: You don't need a capturing group of `$1`. Just use `$&`.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks! Here's another working version with @torazaburo's addition: http://jsfiddle.net/jimcamut/7mb853yc/

Comment: When I run that code snippet, the alert throws up a message box near my mouse pointer that obscures the background post. When I try to drag the box out of the way, it smears the box frame across the screen. The browser does not invalidate and redraw itself where the box was. Not much of a feature.

Comment: @sln which browser are you using?

Comment: IE Version: 11.0.9600.17843

Comment: @sln I am using chrome and it is rendering perfectly..  I also tested on `IE Version: 11.0.9600.17843`.. It is not showing any malfunction..

Comment: How can I post a small screenshot ?

Comment: @sln You can use [this site](http://snag.gy/) here is [mine](http://snag.gy/x6eK5.jpg)

Comment: Ok, [this](http://snag.gy/beRmr.jpg) is my browser, [here](http://snag.gy/HCQjK.jpg) is the smear. I've got default settings for security and privacy.